# Put PHP Code into DIV tag

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to put a PHP code into an div tag? I have already tried this like this one:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $cck->renderPosition( 'projektbild', '', $cck->h( 'projektbild' ) ); ?>')"></div>
```

I know that the one I have posted here, won't work. But is there a way to make this that it works?

Comment: "Didn't work" as in what? Did you look at the generated source to see how it turned out? Did you get an error?

Comment: without content, div heigth remain 0 and background not visible ...

Comment: Is this in a `.php` file? Do you have PHP *installed* on the server? What's the resulting output when you view source?

Comment: Users on StackOverflow will help you, after you help yourself.  Take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  Do some research: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527.
Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The code is part of a seblod template for Joomla. The php code in the div tag is for redndering a position of the template. The problem is that it isn't insert right into the div and now the admin form in the Joomla backend docent works.

Answer (score 0):

The code is part of a seblod template for Joomla. The php code in the div tag is for redndering a position of the template. The problem is that it isn't insert right into the div and now the admin form in the Joomla backend docent works.